# Inverting a function when it becomes complex

Tags: calculus, computational-mathematics

So I am trying to create a cosmological simulator. In the simulator, I need a graph of $a(t)$ vs $t$, where time is in the x-axis as and the cosmic scale factor $a(t) in the y-axis.

In this simulator I am integrating $$dt = H(a)da~~(1)$$

For

$$H(a) = \frac{1}{H_0\sqrt{\Omega_ra(t)^{-1}+\Omega_ma(t)^{-2}+\Omega_{\Lambda}a(t)^2}}$$

This gives me $t(a)$, which is the inverse of the function that I am trying to plot. Here the idea is that I can change $t(a)$ to $a(t)$ just by taking the symmetry of the data points w.r.t $0x=y$ line

There's only one problem. For some values of omega, I get a collapsing universe. Which means something like this,

[image]

**Fig 1:  $a(t)$ vs $t $**

However, from (1) I get the equation of $t(a)$ where a is the independent variable.

To get something like in Figure 1. My function must have 2 parts.

[image]
Fig 2: $t$ vs $a(t)$

Such as $$t_1(a) = 1 +\sqrt{1-a}~~for~~t>1$$  and $$t_2(a) =1 -\sqrt{1-a}~~for~~t<1$$ (These are only the example functions)

So when I invert the function  (which means take the symmetry w.r.t $x=y$ line) I should get something similar to Figure 1.

[image]
Fig 3: Inverting $t(a)$ to $a(t)$ by taking the symmetry w.r.t $x=y$ line.

Which I do.

So in the simulator, I am changing the values of $a$. Concerning Figure 2 something like this should happen:

a(t) starts from 0 goes up to some value (a') at that value H(a) becomes complex ( which is not possible). So after hitting a max value, a(t) should go backward. In reality, it hits complex and gives me an error.

So my question us is there a way to do this using some sort of equation whereas I increase the $a$ it automatically comes back, without need to decrease the value of the $ a$?

I guess it's not possible but I just wanted to ask.

Note: a(t) must be always positive.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect?  Looking at your graph, we see that the maximum value is $5$.  There is no real $t$ with a greater value of $a(t)$ so you should expect the inverse to fail.  For values less than $5$, you will have two inverses (your function is not injective), don't forget to consider both square roots.  For $5$ itself, you have a unique inverse.  For greater than $5$, you will have two complex solutions but no real ones.

It's like solving a simpler problem: the height of a ball thrown vertically upwards.  It will reach a certain maximum height.  For values below that maximum, there will be two times when it is at that height (on the way up and the way down).  For the maximum itself, there will be a unique time.  For above the maximum, there will be no (real) time when it is at that height.

Addition

Remember that you can split a definite integral.  If a function is easier to handle in one form in the range $[0, a)$ and another form in the range $[a, 1]$ then use

$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^a f(x) dx + \int_a^1 f(x) dx
$$

Comment: Well the problem in the function is more complicated.

Comment: @Reign In what way?

Comment: Well its like that $$H(a) = C\sqrt{ka^{-1}+la^{-2}+ma^{2} + n}$$ where $C,k,I,m,n$ are constants. I am doing an computational thing. So every time I increase the da I can only get one t value. I ll edit my question

Comment: A bit messier and some more care may be needed but I think that the same applies.  If only a real solution makes sense and there are no real solutions then there is no solution.  Obtaining a complex solution is just one way that may be indicated.  In my ball example, if it  is thrown fast enough to reach $10$m and you calculate that it will get to $20$m after $10i$s then then the real world answer is that it won't get to $20$m.

Comment: Ofc you are right. I mean its the same thing. The problem is I dont know how to apply it computationally. If I was increasing time instead of $a$ I would get the correct graph. The problem is that I dont have that information. I have $a$ as an independent variable which makes the whole mess

Comment: I edites a bit more. Maybe its more understandble now? I dont know why but ita hard for me to explain the situation